# can't cast string to a boolean?

Tags: coldfusion, boolean

I have one URL `mysite.com/?action=admin:content.form`. Here I am checking whether form is available or not:

```
 <div class="widget-body">
    <div class="widget-toolbox">
    <div class="btn-toolbar">
      <div class="btn-group">
         <cfif ListLast(rc.action,".")>
         <a href="##" class="#local.btn#">
            <i class="icon-plus"></i>
              Add More
         </a>
         </cfif>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

If it exists, then I am going to show a button. If not, then show nothing. I have tried the above but got the error `Can't cast String [form] to a boolean`. Can anyone help me figure out what's going wrong? Thanks

Comment: Then `ListLast` will return the literal string `"form"`. Obviously that is not a boolean value. So you need a different type of comparison (or perhaps a different expression). All depends on your app. For example, you are trying to determine if the last element equals "form", use a simple string comparison, such as `<cfif ListLast(rc.action,".") eq "form"> `

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to check if the the action is form

```
<cfif ListLast(rc.action,".") EQ "form">
```

If you want to check if form variables are present

```
<cfif NOT StructIsEmpty(form)>
```

If you want to know if the there was a `post` action, like in a from

```
<cfif cgi.request_method EQ "post">
```

Comment: First, do not use `IsDefined`. It casts too wide a net. A good example is `IsDefined("form")`. That will *always* return true because CF interprets it as the `FORM` scope.

Comment: Thanks james that's too appreciating.

Comment: http://www.coldfusionmuse.com/index.cfm/2010/2/5/Booleans.and.Coldfusion has the best explanation of boolean in CF